# Is it possible for Android application to implement "RSA/NONE/PKCS1Padding" RSA Encryption

Tags: android, encryption, rsa

So today I've learned that BouncyCastle is the default RSA Encryption Provider on Android and it uses this scheme as a default : "RSA/NONE/NoPadding".

I'm trying to communicate with a server side application that I have written which is currently handling web request and iOS requests. The problem I'm facing is that my server side application has a different default implementation, namely SUN's : "RSA/NONE/PKCS1Padding".

I'm wondering if there is a way for my Android application to implement "RSA/NONE/PKCS1Padding". All the fixes I've seen on articles and questions involve modifying the server side code to implement BouncyCastle. If possible I'd like to stay away from this solution as it involves a lot of work for me to re-work my server-side request processing in order to accommodate Android devices.

Any tips or links to article that I may have overlooked would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't show any code. Have you tried

```
Cipher rsa = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
```

Comment: Ellectronic code book always seems to be a bit of a misnomer ('raw' could be better). But it works with Bouncy, and that's what matters.

Comment: I didn't show any code since it was always changing, anyways I solved the problem by adapting my server side code to use Bouncy Castle as a fallback protocol and it works flawlessly.

Thanks.